# Getting 0 gcov coverage for a mac app

Tags: macos, gcov

I have done the following but I am still getting 0% gcov coverage for my .app.  Here is what I am doing:

1. I am using Xcode 3.2.6, GCC 4.2 and am on Mac OSX 10.6.
2. I duplicated the Debug config and call it Gcov.  In the Gcov config and the app target I set the following build configuration:

   - Check "Generate Test Coverage Files"
   - Check "Instrument Program Flow"
   - Add "-lgcov" to "Other Linker Flags"
3. I did a 'Clean All' then I did a 'Build and Run'.
4. Once the build successfully built it launched the app.  I did some quick things in the app and exited.
5. When I go view the .gcda/.gcno I see that they have been generated and in fact every time I launch the app and do additional things in the app I see the .gcda/.gcno files are indeed updating.  However, using gcov/gcovr to view the .gcda/.gcno I keep getting 0 coverage.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Check to see if your `gcc` is *really* `gcc` with `gcc --version`. On newer Macs, `gcc` is now linked to `llvm-gcc`, which evidently doesn't support `gcov`. If you find that this is the case, use `clang`/`clang++` in lieu of `gcc`/`g++`.