# unable to generate *.gcov on OSX with CppUnit

Tags: macos, gcov, cppunit

There are a number of questions already on this subject, but despite that and the help on SourceForge, I cannot generate a .gcno or .gcda file.

[sample question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643158/code-coverage-with-gcov-cant-produce-gcda-file)

[2nd question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988355/getting-0-gcov-coverage-for-a-mac-app)

My make file compiles and runs my unit tests, but does not generate any output files.  Is there something obviously wrong here?  Commented out lines are things I have tried before.

```
CPP_PLATFORM = Gcc
#CPP_PLATFORM = Clang

#CPPUTEST_CPPFLAGS += -DSUPPRESS_PRINTING
#CPPUTEST_CPPFLAGS += -fprofile-arcs 
#CPPUTEST_CPPFLAGS += -ftest-coverage
#GCOVFLAGS = -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage

#CPPUTEST_LDFLAGS += -lssl  
#CPPUTEST_LDFLAGS += -lcrypto
#CPPUTEST_LDFLAGS += -fprofile-arcs

CPPUTEST_CPPFLAGS = -DSUPPRESS_PRINTING
CPPUTEST_CPPFLAGS = -fprofile-arcs:$(CPPUTEST_CPPFLAGS)
CPPUTEST_CPPFLAGS = -ftest-coverage:$(CPPUTEST_CPPFLAGS)
CPPUTEST_LDFLAGS = -lssl
CPPUTEST_LDFLAGS = -lcrypto:$(CPPUTEST_LDFLAGS)
CPPUTEST_LDFLAGS = -fprofile-arcs:$(CPPUTEST_LDFLAGS)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CPPUTEST_CPPFLAGS += -g -O0 --coverage
#CPPUTEST_CPPFLAGS += -fprofile-arcs 
#CPPUTEST_CPPFLAGS += -ftest-coverage

CPPUTEST_LDFLAGS += -lprofile_rt
```

Either the -g -O0 --coverage or -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage along with the link flag do the trick.  The key was the link flag.